# Swift3, How to use same UITableView in different viewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

In my project, I have table including many cell prototypes, outlets and constraints already in xViewController class.
I would like to know how if I want to use this table again in yViewController class.

Is it possible or I have to create the new one?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ContainerView` for the same. You can take a separate `UITableViewController` or `UIViewController` as per your requirement.Let called this class `CommonTableViewController`.

In your `XViewController` , remove tableview and move all code to  `CommonTableViewController`. Drag and drop container view from the object library on `XViewController`. You can delete pre- defined child of your ContainerView. Now add `embed` segue between `XViewController` and `CommonTableViewController`.

Drag and drop container view on `YViewController` as well and add segue as mentioned above.

Do let me know if you have any further queries.

Answer (score 0):

Refactor your table view controller to its own dedicated storyboard (In Interface Builder: Select the table view controller, and choose on the Menu bar: *Editor > Refactor to Storyboard...*).

Make sure your table view controller is the "Initial View Controller" (has an arrow pointint to it from the left, on the storyboard).

Now, on the main view of every view controller on which you wish to display your table view, insert a Container View and replace the target of the Embed segue with a **Storyboard Reference** to the Table View stotyboard you just created.